# Write a program using java threads to print the following sequence 2 3 4 6 6 9 8 12 10 (Multiple of 2 and 3 in a sequence)

Tags: java, multithreading

Basically what it does is that it prints the following numbers multiple of 2 and 3 in sequence like this

```
 2       3       4       6       6       9       8       12      10    = this is the output
(2*1=2) (3*1=3) (2*2=4) (3*2=6) (2*3=6) (3*3=9) (2*4=8) (3*4=12) (2*5=10) = just a guide
```

here's my code so far, I'm having trouble displaying it in sequence. I've tried using wait and notify but it's a mess. So far this one is working.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final Thread mulof2 = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    int n = 2;
                    int result = n * i;
                    System.out.print(result + " ");
                }
            }
        };
        Thread mulof3 = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    int n = 3;
                    int result = n * i;
                    System.out.print(result + " ");
                }
            }
        };
        mulof2.start();
        mulof3.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why does it need to use threads? Is this homework?

Comment: yes its homework so it has to be threads.

Comment: Then you should tag it as such. I've done it for you.

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I don't know that I can tag it as home work, my bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 7 your first choice should be a `Phaser`. You'll only need one instance of it, created with `new Phaser(1)`. You'll need just two methods for coordination: `arrive` and `awaitAdvance`.

Answer (score 1):

### Multiplication Table in java using Threads Concept

```
public class Multiplication extends Thread {

     public void run() {
         for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
             int n = 2;
             int result = n * i;
             System.out.print(i+"*"+n+"="+result+"\n");
         }
     }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Multiplication mul=new Multiplication();
        mul.start();

        }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a brief explanation of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing *during* computation, you can aggregate the results into strings and then print both strings in order. After joining with the threads of course.

Answer (score 0):

`wait()` and `notify()` are generally too low level, and too complex to use. Try using a more high-level abstraction like `Semaphore`.

You could have a pair of Semaphore instances: one which allows printing the next multiple of 2, and another one which allows printing the next multiple of 3. Once the next multiple of 2 has been printed, the thread should give a permit to print the next multiple of 3, and vice-versa.

Of course, the initial numbers of permits of the semaphores must be 1 for the multiple-of-2 semaphore, and 0 for the other one.

Comment: how should i do that sire? I've never used semaphore instances?

Comment: @philip, then go and read something on thread synchronization using semaphores, otherwise the homework is pointless.

Comment: @philip: Read the javadoc. That's what it's for. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification would help you get the required sequence.

You need to declare a semaphore as other have pointed out `private Semaphore semaphore;`. Then declare another variable to denote which thread has to execute next such as `private int threadToExecute;` .

Next step is within your thread execute the code between `semaphore.acquire();` and `semaphore.release();`

thread2:

```
try{
semaphore.acquire();
if(threadToExecute ==2)
  semaphore.release();

//write your multiply by 2 code here
threadToExecute = 3;

semaphore.release();
}catch(Exception e){
//exceptions
}
```

This will nicely synchronize your output.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that will give you desired results.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final Object lock1 = new Object();
    final Object lock2 = new Object();

    final Thread mulof2 = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                synchronized (lock1) {
                    synchronized (lock2) {
                        lock2.notify();
                        int n = 2;
                        int result = n * i;
                       printResult(result);
                    }
                    try {
                        lock1.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
    };
    Thread mulof3 = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                synchronized (lock2) {
                    synchronized (lock1) {
                         lock1.notify();
                         int n = 3;
                         int result = n * i;
                         printResult(result);
                    }
                    try {
                        lock2.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };
    mulof2.start();
    mulof3.start();

}

static void printResult(int result)
{
    try {
        // Sleep a random length of time from 1-2s
         System.out.print(result + " ");
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

}